# How to execute SQL query (sql server database) in Jenkins Pipeline using groovy?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I need to execute an sql query on server sql database using Jenkins Pipeline script

I'm new to using Jenkins Pipeline and I couldn't find a clear documentation. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You need to first set up the SQL client/command-line tool in Jenkins master or agent

after that, you can write a Jenkins pipeline that will invoke the SQL command in the shell or command, the way you do it in your local machine

```
node('node_LableName_Where_Ever_You_Install_The_SQLClient') {
  stage('invoke sql command') {
    sh """
      sqlplus username/password@connect_identifier
      select * from tab;
    """
  }
}
```